# Match pattern in line using grep

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, grep

I need to grep lines from a file with comma separated values, and direct the output to another file.  Thus, if the second value starts with 'U' and the last value is 'Success', then this line matches the pattern.

Should match the pattern:

```
324,U63@DOM1,U63@DOM1,C1755,C1755,Kerberos,Network,LogOn,Success
```

Should fail to match:

```
456,C1164$@DOM1,C1164$@DOM1,C625,C625,?,Network,LogOff,Success
123,U63@DOM1,C11847$@?,C2109,C2109,?,?,TGT,Fail
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a service for writing programs because you don't want to.

Comment: `^[^,]+,U.*Success$`

Comment: @Natecat: note that the `+` requires `grep -E` (aka `egrep`).

Comment: Thank you @jonathan.  This works!

Comment: Does it have to be done with `grep`? This seems like it would be clearer if you used `awk`.

Comment: @Gene, in questions these simple, what have you trieds simply submerge in the flood of correct answers. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As columnar matching requirements become more complex, an `awk` solution becomes more attractive:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /^U/ && $(NF) == "Success"'
```

(The default action of the match is to print the line.)

Here is the solution using `grep` though:

```
grep '^[^,]*,U.*,Success$'
```

And `sed`:

```
sed '/^[^,]*,U.*,Success$/ p; d'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '^[^,]*,U.*,Success$'
```

Look for the first comma, a `U`, the last comma, `Success` and end of line.